# Adding svgr to create-react-app via craco

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, craco

I want to use [svgr's webpack plugin](https://react-svgr.com/docs/webpack/) with create-react-app to [use SVGs with MaterialUI's SvgIcon.](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/) I'm using [craco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco) to add svgr to Webpack's config.

Currently, whenever the SVG is supposed to be rendered, the following error is thrown:

```
Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('static/media/googlelogo.03ad8507.svg') is not a valid name.
```

My craco.config.js:

```js
const CracoAlias = require("craco-alias");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: CracoAlias,
      options: {
        baseUrl: "./src",
        tsConfigPath: "./tsconfig.extend.json",
        source: "tsconfig"
      }
    }
  ],
  webpack: {
    configure: (config, { env, paths }) => {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ["@svgr/webpack"]
      });
      return config;
    }
  }
};
```

How do I embed the SVG properly?

Comment: if you want to add a loader, use `unshift()` instead of `push()` to give your loader high priority

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It looks like CRA supports converting SVGs by default, thus making craco+svgr redundant.

```
import { ReactComponent as GoogleLogo } from "../assets/images/googlelogo.svg";
```

`GoogleLogo` is a component now.

`ReactComponent` is a required magic string.

Comment: This is awesome - you have any documentation links on this at all, just out of curiosity?

Comment: @prestonsmith https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#adding-svgs

Comment: It looks like CRA already supports this feature without CRACO.

Comment: This hint is amazing! Does not work with my antd setup though....

import {Icon} from 'antd';
import {ReactComponent as Tree} from '../../images/tree.svg';
<Icon component={Tree} />