# antd: Add custom svg icons

Tags: reactjs, svg, antd

I am using CRA so I can import an svg as a React Component directly like so:

```
import { ReactComponent as Tree } from "../assets/images/tree.svg";
```

See this post as reference: [Adding svgr to create-react-app via craco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60074103/adding-svgr-to-create-react-app-via-craco)

So I thought I could use this now and drop it into the antd icon component:

```
 <Icon component={Tree} />
```

But all the console is giving me is a

```
Warning: [antd: Icon] Empty Icon
```

even though the svg file exists, the path is correct and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at this Demo on the sandbox , It might help you if you just copied and pasted into your project.
https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-brook-lckzw?file=/src/App.js

I just used a very basic config for craco and installed these libs

- "@ant-design/icons": "4.0.0"
- "@craco/craco": "^6.4.0"

Comment: Thx so much, now it works! My fault was that I've imported Icon from 'antd' and not from '@ant-design/icons'