# How to import SVG in ReactJS with craco?

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack, craco

I'm struggling to import SVG's when I'm using craco in my react app.

It's suggested to use [@svgr/webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@svgr/webpack) but I'm not sure how to put it into my craco.config.js

My current setup as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60074103/adding-svgr-to-create-react-app-via-craco) (I prob shouldn't follow someone's config that doesn't work and expect it to work tho) that does not work:

```js
// craco.config.js
const CracoAlias = require("craco-alias");

module.exports = {
   plugins: [
     {
        plugin: CracoAlias,
        options: {
           source: "tsconfig",
           baseUrl: "./src",
           tsConfigPath: "./tsconfig.paths.json"
        }
     },
    ],
    webpack: {
       configure: (config, { env, paths }) => {
         config.module.rules.push({
           test: /\.svg$/,
           use: ["@svgr/webpack"]
         });
         return config;
       }
     }
};
```

The craco.config.js webpack documentation is [here](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco/README.md#configuration-file) but it's so confusing to me without concrete examples.

Also to note:
Writing `import {ReactComponent as mySvg} from "./mySvg.svg"` doesn't work because it doesn't recognize it as a ReactComponent.

If I try importing directly via `import mySvg from "./mySvg.svg"` Typescript doesn't recognize the file.

What I'm currently doing is putting the svg into a React component and using that but it's a nightmare doing that every time. I also put this in `@types/custom.d.ts`, but it still doesn't work when put into `<img src={mySvg} />`

```
// @types/custom.d.ts
declare module "*.svg" {
    const content: any;
    export default content;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

import {reactComponent as GoogleLogo} from "../assets/image/googlelogo.svg;

GoogleLogo is component and reactComponent is a required magic string

i find the fix your problem in [Adding svgr to create-react-app via craco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60074103/adding-svgr-to-create-react-app-via-craco)

Comment: Appreciate the effort but it doesn't work for me. I edited my answer above regarding this too. Based on [this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#adding-svgs) it requires react-scripts and I'm using craco, I think that's why it doesn't work. Or something else I'm doing wrong - possibly my config is wrong, or something else.

Comment: CRACO relies on CRA which _is_ react-scripts